# blackberry parameterised are only available if source level 1.5

Tags: java, blackberry

When i user vector object in my blackberry app like below

```
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
```

i am getting compiler error as

**blackberry parameterised are only available if source level 1.5**

*why is this error***?**

Comment: That's the specific error? Really?

Comment: Basically it's telling you that generics are only available from Java 1.5 upwards. Make sure that your compiler (or IDE or build tool or ...) is configured to compile your code with at least a Java 5-level compiler (setting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlackBerry is based on JavaME which is currently limited to Java 1.3 syntax.  Thus, since generics were added in Java 5 (1.5), you are out of luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Classes compiled for the BlackBerry must use version 1.3 of Java, which precludes things like generics and enums. On top of that, the classes that are supported are very limited and do not include the collections classes.

However, the BlackBerry does provide a number of [custom collection classes](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/collection/util/package-summary.html) that pre-date the standard ones. You may wish to use these if the facilities provided by Vector and Hashtable are not adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Generics/Parameterized types were added in Java 5.0 (2004) Before this version, the feature didn't exist.

IMHO Vector is a legacy collection which was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998) but is still supported. You should consider using ArrayList if you can.

Comment: i think ArrayList(import java.util.ArrayList;) not supported in blackberry

Comment: @evan, interesting, it has Generics, but not a basic collection which is 13 years old. In that case, you have to use Vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not have Generics either -- limited to (subset of) Java 1.3 :(

Comment: @scott, this make it suprising it has the error message at all. Java 1.3 wouldn't produce such as error. The message implies that a source level of 1.5 is possible.

Comment: me currently using jdk version 1.6.0_10 and Blackberry JRE version 5.0.0 , do i have to change any version of above two and i am using eclipse

Comment: You have to configure your project to use 1.3 as the source and target versions if you haven't already done so.

Comment: You might be better off using Java 1.3, given this is the target platform. :P If you are using Java 6, I suggest using update 24 rather than update 10.

Comment: Java 1.3 can only be used if you're using command line tools or if you're using a fairly old version of the JDE. The most recent tools (JDE or Eclipse) require a newer version of Java. That's why I said to set the source and target options.

Comment: Eclipse has a built in compiler, but I thought you had a choice.