# Can we use generic or collection classes in blackberry app development

Tags: generics, blackberry, collections, java

I am a newbie in blackberry app development.
I am making a Blackberry Project using BB JRE 5.0.
And i want to integrate another project into it 
which is working fine with J2SE 1.5. How can i achieve this.
Is it possible?
If no, then how to use generic and collection classes in blackberry
development. means which BB JRE supports collection and generic classes.
Please suggest me some alternative, i ll be very thankful to you all.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [There isn't chance to use generics in Blackberry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946011/902217)

Comment: possible duplicate of [blackberry parameterised are only available if source level 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945863/blackberry-parameterised-are-only-available-if-source-level-1-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry Java SDK does not support generics and Collections classes from Java 2 Standard Edition.

RAPC compiler (BlackBerry compiler) compiles your java files with `-target 1.3` option, which means that binary code should be compatible with java 1.3. And there are no generics.

Also you cannot use enums and all java 1.5 stuff.

Only classes listed in RIM Java API are available.

Check this link for the most recent Java API javadoc:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/index.html?net/rim/device/api/crypto/keystore/package-summary.html